# Torrent client for Ubuntu similar to uTorrent

Tags: ubuntu, utorrent

What is the best alternative under Ubuntu for torrent client that has functionality close to uTorrent under Windows? Particularly performance, webgui, folder watch, labeling, compatibility with most torrent clients, UPnP.

Answer (score 2):

First one that springs to mind is Transmission. I haven't used it that much, but it's pretty similar from memory.

Comment: I have used it but it's not what I like...

Comment: Transmission sucks. Torrents never goes to finish. They are either seeding or paused. I couldn't find any option to stop torrents either. Oh boy switching from utorrent is not easy.

Answer (score 1):

ktorrent is very good indeed.

utorrent does run just about fine under wine, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [**Deluge**](http://deluge-torrent.org/)? You can find it in the **Ubuntu Software Center**.

### EDIT

It seems that there is a **Linux version coming out soon** ([source](http://torrentfreak.com/utorrent-for-linux-is-coming-finally-100601/)).

Comment: This looks interesting..