# Best bittorent client for Linux

Tags: linux, bittorrent, utorrent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Torrent client for Ubuntu similar to uTorrent](https://superuser.com/questions/177773/torrent-client-for-ubuntu-similar-to-utorrent)

What is a good bittorent client for Linux?

So far I used uTorrent on Windows, but recently I moved to Fedora and I saw that uTorrent doesn't support Linux.

BTW: If there's any way to run uTorrent on Linux without Wine it would be awesome :)

Thanks.

Comment: Related http://superuser.com/questions/177773/torrent-client-for-ubuntu-similar-to-utorrent

Comment: If there is some way this question is different from the linked duplicate, please flag and let us know. Otherwise, this is closed as a duplicate question.

Answer (score 4):

[Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/). Very nice interface, cross platform. And it's free and open-source.

Answer (score 1):

I find transmission to be a good torrent client.  Simple but effective.

Answer (score 1):

uTorrent works quite perfectly in combination with WINE (Transparant Windows environment on Linux). Furthermore, if you must use uTorrent, a Linux version is announced here:

http://torrentfreak.com/utorrent-for-linux-is-coming-finally-100601/

Answer (score 0):

[Comparison of BitTorrent clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients)

This is a question for google, not for superuser.

Comment: -1 because of Google. This question IS for SuperUser, as agreed [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1445/are-some-questions-too-easy-for-superuser)

Answer (score 0):

Give [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/) a try. IMO its the closest to uTorrent for Windows.